# Adding a keyfile to PHP cURL authentication

Tags: php, authentication, curl

I try to upload a file to a backup server with PHP & cURL and keyfile authentication. I created a pair pf public & private keys and stored the public one on the backup server. The private key I uploaded to the web server in a file called "private_key.txt".
Login works perfectly, when I load the private key file into filezilla for authentification, so the backup server should be set up right. With PHP cURL I keep getting an "Authentication failure" message.

Here´s my script:

```
$certpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'private_key.txt';
$curl = curl_init();
$fp = fopen('testfile_ORIG', 'r');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"sftp://server.com/is/htdocs/testfile_MOVED");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, 'user');   
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $certpath);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLENGINE, 'ssh-rsa');   
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);      
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);

curl_exec ($curl);
echo curl_error($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
```

Does anyone see my failure?
I Tried around with different settings for 2 days, but won´t get it to work.
Thank you for all hints

Answer (score 0):

your code never checks if your curl_setopt calls fails, fix that, and the error should become clear. maybe something like

```
function ecurl_setopt ( /*resource*/$ch , int $option , /*mixed*/ $value ):bool{
    $ret=curl_setopt($ch,$option,$value);
    if($ret!==true){
        //option should be obvious by stack trace
        throw new RuntimeException ( 'curl_setopt() failed. curl_errno: ' . return_var_dump ( curl_errno ($ch) ).'. curl_error: '.curl_error($ch) );
    }
    return true;
}
```

- it throws an exception instead of returning bool(false) if curl_setopt fails.

your actual problem here is (probably) that you assume $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ends with a [directory separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Representations_of_paths_by_operating_system_and_shell) (`/` in mac/linux/bsd/etc systems, `\` in windows systems), that is incorrect, it doesn't, so lets say your www root is `/srv/http/default/www` , and your private key file is `/srv/http/default/www/private_key.txt` , your code will try to access the file named `wwwprivate_key.txt` in the folder `/srv/http/default`, instead of trying to access the file named `private_key.txt` in the folder `/srv/http/default/www` - the solution:

```
$certpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'private_key.txt';
```

(the constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is 1 of [php's global constants](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php), it's set to `\` on windows systems, and `/` everywhere else.)

Comment: Ok, I fixed the path to the key file but still not working. The whole path is /is/htdocs/account123/www/projectfolder/private_key.txt 

The function shows me an error in this line:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLENGINE, 'ssh-rsa');
I don´t really know what to type in here. Any other ideas?

Comment: @user3475261 unless you know what you're doing, you probably don't want to mess with CURLOPT_SSLENGINE in the first place. leave it alone, or read up on https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/README.ENGINE